# Negating expression in bash double bracket

Tags: bash

How can I negate the expression as the following matches a numeric check.

```
  elif [[ $pn =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
    pfm -w "pn failed numeric inspection"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may negate the test using

```bsh
[[ ! $pn =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]
```

or, in this case,

```bsh
[ -z "$pn" ] || [[ $pn =~ [^[:digit:]] ]]
```

i.e., "is `$pn` empty or does it contain a non-digit?"

Or, with a globbing test,

```bsh
[ -z "$pn" ] || [[ $pn == *[![:digit:]]* ]]
```

or, using an extended globbing pattern,

```bsh
[[ $pn != +([[:digit:]]) ]]
```

Comment: Or: `! [[ .... ` may also work.